# mDNSResponder process taking over 1GB of memory

Tags: macos, memory, monterey

The mDNSResponder process is taking a huge amount of memory on my machine.  I have limited troubleshooting skills with MacOS (more of my experience has been with Windows systems).  I tried killing this process with sudo killall mDNSResponder, which kills the process but it starts back up and I can see the process in Activity Monitor grow back to use over **1GB** of memory.  I have a 2016 MacBook Pro w/16GB memory running Monterey, version 12.6.8.  I also have rebooted but the process continues to be the top process in Activity Monitor with such a large about of memory used.  Other than completing re-installing MacOS clean and then restoring data from backup, are there other things I can check to try to determine why it's consuming so much memory?

Comment: Is there any special network activity on your Mac, or any non-default network settings?

Comment: None that I know of, although I was looking at Startup items and I found a launch daemon called start_micromdm that I disabled, it looks like it is from two canoes.com.  I also uninstalled both of the VPN apps that I had previously used (IPVanish and NordVPN).  I was hoping this may have fixed it, but it did not.  I did a full power down and restart but mDNSResponder is still using over 1GB of memory.

Comment: Is this your own laptop or is it managed by someone else (micromdm incidates a MDM of some kind)?

Comment: Are you connected to work or home?

Comment: Yes, this is my own laptop, it is not managed by someone else.  In the past, I had used it to VPN into my work network, but I no longer do that anymore.  After looking up start_micromdm, I initially disabled it but then I actually deleted the start_micromdm.plist file from /Library/LaunchDaemons.  I am not connected to work, I only connect to the Internet from home.